# Cannot include std header file in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, com, include

I am new to c++ programming,

I have a c++ project developed in visual studio 2010, and now I am developping a COM project in VS2008.
In this project I have to include some files used in the c++ project (developed in VS2010).

When I tried to include a header file from the C++ project (developed in VS2010), the compiler gives error `"cannot find stdint.h file"`.

Is this problem with my installed visual studio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The stdint.h file is only available with vs2010 and not with vs2008. As a temporary solution you can copy the stdint.h file from include folder of an installed visual studio 2010, (c:\ProgramFiles\VS\include\stdint.h) and add that to your 2008 project.